# How to select this element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this piece of HTML code.

```
<div class="row member-item">
    <div class="col-md-3"><img src={{ i.mem_imgurl }}></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">姓名<br><div class="mem_name">{{ i.mem_name }}</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">组别<br><div class="mem_group">{{ i.mem_group }}</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">年级<br><div class="mem_year">{{ i.mem_year }}</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteNode" onclick="delNode(this)">Delete</button></div>
</div>
```

And I write js as follows,

```
function delNode(btn) {
    var mem_item = $(btn).parent().parent();
    var mem_name = $(mem_item).children("div.mem_name").text();
    alert(mem_name);
    console.log(mem_name);
    mem_item.hide()
}
```

I want to get the text value of div.mem_name, but somehow it just does not work:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `children` function only travels down the immediate children of the element. You can use `find` to search down the tree of children. This should work:

```
var mem_name = $(mem_item).find("div.mem_name").text();
```

This is from the jQuery [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) documentation:

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

Similarly, your `parent().parent()` call can be replaced with [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```
var mem_item = $(btn).parents(".member-item");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.closest` and `.find` together

**Script :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".deleteNode").click(function(){    
                var mem_name = $(this).closest('.row').find('.mem_name').text();
                alert(mem_name);
                console.log(mem_name);
            });
        });
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="row member-item">
    <div class="col-md-3"><img src=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">姓名<br><div class="mem_name">name</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">组别<br><div class="mem_group">mem_group</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">年级<br><div class="mem_year">mem_year</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteNode" >Delete</button></div>
</div>
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fdr24wf8/2/)